# Retrofit Enqueue parsing a Json object without an additional class

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have working code that allows me parse the Json files I get from a retrofit API get call. However, the way I am currently doing it requires two classes (one of which is just a list containing the other), and if I was wondering if it is possible to do this with a single data class. More explanation is below.

**What I have:**

*Interface:*

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET(value = "all_people.php")
    fun getAllPeople(): Call<People>
}
```

*Code:*

```
retrofit: ApiInterface = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
retrofit.getAllPeople().enqueue(object : Callback<People?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<People?>, response: Response<People?>) {
               Log.d("First person", responce.body()!!.people[0])
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<People?>, t: Throwable) {}
        })
```

*Data classes:*

```
data class Person (
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String
)
data class People (
    val people: List<Person>
)
```

**THIS IS WORKING**

The issue is that this requires an additional class (People). This is because I am getting back from the API a JSON object (Which contains the JSON array I want to access). This is the solution I have found online when I look at scenarios like this, however, this method requires me to create an additional class, containing just a list, for every different API call I have. Which is obviously not ideal.

**Question:** My question is how would I do this while eliminating the class People?

**I want to do something like this:**

*Interface:*

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET(value = "all_people.php")
    fun getAllPeople(): Call<List<Person>>
}
```

*Code:*

```
retrofit: ApiInterface = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
retrofit.getAllPeople().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Person>?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Person>?>, response: Response<List<Person>?>) {
//The issue is here, because this is a Json object, and I am treating it like a list
//Is there a way of access the Json array inside this Json object without creating the person class?
               Log.d("First person", responce.body()!![0]) 
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Person>?>, t: Throwable) {}
        })
```

However, I can't figure out how to "open" the Json obect to get this to work and therefore get this error code:

Comment: responce.body()  must be a object type List<Person>

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that worked, but I don't think it is ideal.
Rather than use the GsonConverter that is inbuild to retrofit, I do it myself.

inside onResponse I do the following

```
val peopleList = GsonBuilder()
                    .create()
                    .fromJson(response.body()!!.getAsJsonArray("people"), Array<Person>::class.java).toList()
Log.d("First person", peopleList!![0])
```

I am not at all sure this is better then just having extra data classes though

Comment: if response.body   is not  already a List<Person>, then  include the serialize in the .addConverterFactory, add it in onResponse  is no a good idea.